# FIND formula, Correlation Table

Tags: excel

I have a correlation table like so:

[image]

I want to make a static formula that can produce the following outcome for a large correlation table. There are 2 parts, the #, and the text. I can imagine the # and text needs to be parsed and then the formula to be applied.

IF # 's are equal, produce 1, if not produce .35
IF text are equal  produce 1, if not product .99
if both are equal produce 1.

I've tried something like IF(A2=B1,1,.99) thus far but this misses alot of what i'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the numbers and text always separated by `_`?

Comment: @ScottCraner , Yes scott, I can however make it so they are not. ie 1curve1, 2curve1, 3curve3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(B$1,FIND("_",B$1)-1)=LEFT($A2,FIND("_",$A2)-1),1,0.35)*IF(MID(B$1,FIND("_",B$1)+1,LEN(B$1))=MID($A2,FIND("_",$A2)+1,LEN($A2)),1,0.99)
```

Then copy over and down.

[image]

Comment: @Jonnyboi practice.